# Can github for windows be used as a COM object

Tags: git, github

I installed GitHub for windows (not to be confused with GitGUI which is also installed). A rather nice and simple UI for working with GIT

Can the running instance of GitHub for windows be automated? I would love to execute commands such as GIT status from that running instance of GitHub.

If above not possible, then is it easy to grab + take the running instance of GitHub and then execute Git commands based on the currently selected archive? I am willing to shell out to cmd.exe and do things like git status, but I would want to use the currently selected archive that GitHub for windows is currently using if COM automation is not possible. (so how to read/get the currently selected archive and user settings and shell to git is a path I a open to. I do note that if you right click on the archive, and shell out to git.exe, then the currently selected archive with user settings is selected. So how to shell out to git.exe with current user archive/settings would also be a possible solution.

And as an alternative, a .net library to work with GIT could also be turned into a standard windows COM object. This would allow ease of GIT from windows scripting, or even VBA.

Last but not least - I also wiling to hit the web site using the  git api, but then I would have to supply the user/archive info - so I open to this approach also.